# Changing caller ID in twilio

Tags: twilio

Call is made from an **IVR num 044xxxxxxxx** to a **number A**. User on number A listens to IVR msgs and when user presses 5 
dial function is called and a child call is made between **number A** and **number B**.
Issue is number B sees incoming caller ID as **044xxxxxxxx** instead of number A.
My question is can we shown caller ID  of **number A** to **number B**

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you initiate the call from Twilio, then you can only use valid Caller IDs from within your account. That is, either Twilio bought numbers or [numbers you have verified](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-Adding-a-Verified-Phone-Number-or-Caller-ID-with-Twilio) with Twilio.

The only time in which a callerId is passed from one user's phone to another is if you are [directly forwarding a call using `<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#callerid).